# How add variable –es.tags-as-fields.all –es.index-prefix –es.server-urls to jaeger yaml config?

Tags: jaeger

I run `./jaeger-all-in-one --es.tags-as-fields.all=true --es.index-prefix=myteam.jaeger --es.server-urls=http://ip-server:9200`

How add the variables `--es.tags-as-fields.all`, `--es.index-prefix` and `--es.server-urls` to the YAML config ?

```
./jaeger-all-in-one --config-file=/etc/jaeger-config.yaml
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each "dot" would be a new child node in the YAML file, like:

```
es:
  tags-as-fields:
    all: true
  index-prefix: myteam-jaeger
  server-urls: "http://ip-server:9200"
```

Make sure to run the process with the env var SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE set to elasticsearch, like:

```
SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch jaeger-all-in-one --config-file=/etc/jaeger-config.yaml
```

(as seen on https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/issues/1299)